# PHP Not Handling/Responding to XMLHTTP POST Request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

In my JS, I send a post request using XMLHttpRequest. Checking the network tab reveals a status code of 200. However, my PHP Script doesn't handle the request correctly.
Here is the JS:

```
let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("code")[0];
let contents = textarea.innerHTML;
let post = 'action="save"&contents=' + contents;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if( xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200 ){
        console.log( xhr.responseText );
    }
    };
    xhr.open('POST', "http://testingserverjts.infinityfreeapp.com/FileManager/edit.php");
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(post);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (xhr.status === 200){
            document.innerHTML += "<div class='banner'>Saved</div>";
        }
    }
```

And here is the PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST["action"])){
    echo "posting";
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Can Anyone Help

Comment: Why, in this day and age, are you still using XMLHttpRequest rather than Fetch?

Comment: Because the server I am using had issues with fetch due to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header being missing and I couldnt find a way around it

Comment: your php script has an error - `file_get_contents(): Filename cannot be empty` and the error you mention - have you set that header in PHP correctly and have you, in `fetch` used the `mode:'cors'` config parameter?

Comment: a `textarea` incidentally has a value rather than `innerHTML`

Comment: A simple `var_dump($_POST, $_GET);` would give you an idea of what is being sent to your PHP code.

Comment: `had issues with fetch due to the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header being missing`...fetch doesn't cause that directly. But anyway that's a story for another day

Comment: `action="save"`...why the double quotes? You don't need that. Shouldn't matter, but you don't need them

Comment: `doesn't handle the request correctly`...in what way? What did you expect, and what did you get instead? You didn't actually explain the problem fully. Did you look at the Response tab of the request in the Network tool, to see the raw response? Your JS code makes no attempt to show you the output from PHP, so that is the only place you would see it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with XMLHttpRequest when being used like this @ProfessorAbronsius . I would also use fetch, but XMLHttpRequest is still valid tech.